# Loading post that has visual composer data inside lightbox?

Tags: plugins, lightbox

I'm trying to load this post http://tropicalzero.com/project/me-gigaset/ inside the lightbox that opens on the first portfolio item at http://tropicalzero.com/portfolio/.
All of this content is dummy that I've imported to figure out how to do it.
I managed to open the content inside the lightbox but for some reason it's breaking the visual composer data completely. Is there something that I'm forgetting here?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is not working is because you are trying to embed VC inside the lightbox modal.

VC shortcodes would work inside the post/pages of wordpress but not on modals.

I don't know if a paid add-on plugin called "Modal Popup Box For Visual Composer" would help you. It gives yous the ability to make vc content appear on modals but I'm not sure it would work inside the lightbox. (I also don't know which lightbox plugin you use, they are so many).

Hope this helps